# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:

Tags: magento-1.8, sql

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (musice1g_musiciansmall.shipusa_singleboxes, CONSTRAINT FK_shipusa_singlebox_sku_entity FOREIGN KEY (sku) REFERENCES catalog_product_entity (sku) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I am using Magento platform for my E-commerce website. I'm new to coding and sql language. Can someone please explain me why is this happenning and how can I solve this error. I have tried installing an extension for Dimensional Shipping and when i try entering the dimensions for any product and saving this is the error i get.

After reading a lot on google for a day I have given up for now and seek help. I am able to open AdminControl and Cpanel for my website. I tried to do a few things in PHPmyadmin but they didn't work for me. I kep't on getting errors.

Comment: I accessed musice1g_musiciansmall.shipusa_singleboxes in PHPmyadmin and there is no data in that table. What code should i enter for everything to work.

Comment: You need to contact the third party extension developer. It probably will be something quite familiar to them and you'll get it fixed quicker as otherwise you'll be waiting here until someone who actually has installed it and also had the same problem just happens to read the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support. Contact the developer.

Answer (score 1):

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (musice1g_musiciansmall.shipusa_singleboxes, CONSTRAINT FK_shipusa_singlebox_sku_entity FOREIGN KEY (sku) REFERENCES catalog_product_entity (sku) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

This error says, that the database is unable to write something to a table `musice1g_musiciansmall`, because the `sku` you have in the writing can not be found in `catalog_product_entity`